# Converting negative value to zero

Tags: core-language

I would like to convert the negative outcome of $r_2$  to zero. I have used the following code, but it still gives me a negative value. Is there any option to turn the negative outcome directly to zero? I already set the different random value of `γ`.

```
FullSimplify[Subscript[r, 2] -> (γ Subscript[c, 1] , Subscript[r, 2] > 0]
```

Comment: You could use `UnitStep[]` for this...

Comment: Change the definition of r_2 so that it returns zero for negative values.

Comment: Or `Clip[..., {0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: try [Ramp](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html)?